# Create app activity with next and back buttons

Tags: java, android

I have an activity in my Android app with `currentIndex`. I need to iterate it trough array `exampleArray` step-by-step. When user presses `nextButton`, app goes to the next item in `exampleArray`, `% exampleArray.length` is needed to jump to the beginning of array. How to make `backButton` jump from the beginning to the end of array AND, for example, go from 3rd to 2nd item in array (decrease normally)?

```
nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % exampleArray.length;
        updateItem(); // uses value of currentIndex to find needed exampleArray item
    }
});

backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        currentIndex = // do something, idk what
        updateItem();
    }
});
```

UPD: @AshishRanjan 's code does what I need. TY man.

Comment: `(exampleArray.length + currentIndex -1) % exampleArray.length`

Comment: replace from `currentIndex = // do something, idk what` to `currentIndex -= 1;`

Comment: @VELFER If AshishRanjan solutions works for you then you should accept it as answers.

Comment: @SagarTrehan Want to but can't. Comments can't be marked as answers. Only answers can. And I need to wait 2 days to mark mine as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `(exampleArray.length + currentIndex -1) % exampleArray.length` – Ashish Ranjan

Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `(exampleArray.length + currentIndex -1) % exampleArray.length` it shows the previous item in the app.

Comment: But if the button is pressed again, the index will not decrease, but stay the same.

Comment: Of course, because @VELFR wants to jump to the end of the array EACH time the "backbutton" is pressed. That's why the index needs to stay the same and should not decrease every click.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't complete. I've updated it.

Comment: Not really. The question wasn't very explicit, but you could understand the behaviour.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question right now. Please edit it again! 
Do you want to jump to the end of array OR to the previous array item? You can't do both! (except if you make a new view, only show it on backbutton click, otherwise hide it, more stuff .....)

Comment: i concretized your question for clarfication